# How to select * in addition to group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider a PostgreSQL table with fields a-z

```
a, b, c ... z
-------------
5, 6, 2 ... 9
5, 6, 3 ... 1
```

I'd like to do a group on fields `a,b` and keep only records where b was maximum.

```
SELECT a, max(b) as b, c, d, e ... z
FROM table
GROUP BY a, b
```

This works fine, but it's annoying to have to type out all the values in SELECT.  I'd much rather do something like

```
SELECT max(b) as b, * 
FROM TABLE
```

But doing so gives error

> [42803] ERROR: column "table.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
> be used in an aggregate function.

Any idea how to avoid having to type all the column names in a lengthy table when doing a groupby operation?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by a order by b desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Actually, in Postgres, the fastest method is usually `distinct on`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by a, b desc;
```

With an index on `(a, b desc)` this should be the fastest method.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - your answer and reference to distinct on led me to the answer I posted.  I'm not quite following your second code snippet because you mention `distinct on` but don't use it...  also wow 1M rep crazy

Answer (score 1):

Gordon Linoff's answer put me on the right track, namely using `distinct on`.  This works in postgres

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a, b) *
FROM table
ORDER BY a, b DESC
```

Basically it lists the distinct rows of (a,b) and sorts them in order, hence taking only the first or last value depending on sort order.  Actually surprised this works...